# fetching records from solr doesn't update id in data-import.xml file

Tags: solr

I'm fetching records from database in solr. Every time i execute, it fetches all the records from the database. I need to update my data-import.xml such that it only fetch records that are not fetched yet(or >= some_table_id).
How should i achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen [Delta Import Example](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Delta-Import_Example) and [Uploading structured data](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#the-sql-entity-processor)?

Comment: yea, but it doesn't seem to resolve my problem

Comment: Well, that's how you implement a delta import - i.e. how to only fetch those entries that have changed since the last time you imported. Why doesn't it work properly for your use case? What did you try that failed?

Comment: I m using sql query: `select * from table_name where tbl_id>=1` to fetch records from database. I need every time i execute the solr to fetch records, it should update the tbl_id in data-import.xml file. The next time solr fetches data, it will fetch after that id, but in my case the tbl_id not get updated and every time solr fetches full data from database.

Comment: The examples above show how you can use a timestamp column together with the last imported time to only get those entries that have changed since the last import. Changing just the `id` will not catch rows that have changed since the last import happened.

Comment: I have written a script which updates the id in data-import file with the latest database id. Everytime i run the script, solr fetches the data above that id and that solved my problem. @MatsLindh Thanks for your inputs.